# WiFi sometimes doesn't reconnect after resuming from suspend on Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, network-manager, suspend

This has happened at least twice so far.

I am running Kubuntu 15.04. Sometimes, when I resume work after suspend, the wifi connection doesn't go back up. Here is a part of `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC NetworkManager[591]: <info> wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC NetworkManager[591]: <info> waking up...
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC NetworkManager[591]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC NetworkManager[591]: <info> (eth0): preparing device
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC NetworkManager[591]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC NetworkManager[591]: <info> (wlan0): preparing device
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC NetworkManager[591]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC wpa_supplicant[753]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC wpa_supplicant[753]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC NetworkManager[591]: <warn> could not get interface properties: No readable properties in this interface.
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC NetworkManager[591]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC NetworkManager[591]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Oct 27 18:25:56 LenovoPC NetworkManager[591]: <warn> could not get interface properties: No readable properties in this interface.
```

Restarting NetworkManager (`sudo service NetworkManager restart`) helps.

What does it mean that the device is "managed" and that the interface has no readable properties? How do I fix it?

**UPD:** I still have this on Kubuntu 15.10.

Comment: I have the same problem on Kubuntu 15.10. My notebook is a ThinkPad X250.

Comment: Maybe [launchpad bug 1439771](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1439771)?

Answer (score 2):

adding a systemd hook on 15.10 this seemed to work for me:

/etc/systemd/system/root-resume.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Local system resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```